# Fetching all rows as Object with pdo php

Tags: php, pdo, fetch

I know that the function fetchObject (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php) gives me the next row as an object of the specified class, but I want to get all the rows as an object of the specified class, does PDO has some function to this or I have to do it manually???

THanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`](https://php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchall.php):

> `PDOStatement::fetchAll` — Returns an array containing all of the result set rows

Example usage:

```
$arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class_name, $constructor_args);
```

If you do not need all of the objects in a single array, you will probably find iterating through all the rows to work just as well:

```
while ($obj = $stmt->fetchObject($class_name, $constructor_args)) {
    // Process $obj
}
```

Comment: @tim do you know why `fetchAll()` is so slow, how can one makes it faster.

Comment: @meda:  How many rows are you trying to fetch?  PHP has to store all of the rows in an array before the function will return.  See my updated answer for another possible solution.

Comment: Sometimes it's just a few rows(4-5), I find `fetch()` much faster but it's just more code because of the loop. you get my vote